# How to create slug URL from title using laravel-6?

Tags: laravel, slug

I was using str_slug method. But something is error like this "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\str_slug()"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you spelled it wrong. Should be Str::slug(...), also make sure you have the `use` statement on top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
```

Docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-slug).

Comment: Yeah, I think the array and string helper functions were depreciated in v5.8 and removed in 6.

Comment: By the way, Str and Arr facades are aliased, so you don't need the full namespace.  `use Str;` is enough.

Comment: I attached a link to helpers of v6, and I see Str::slug() there

Comment: Right, all I meant was that the old `str_slug()` way of accessing that behavior is gone now.

Comment: Right, I guess you can just use Str::slug() then or just define your own str_slug() helper

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new file /app/Helper/Helper.php
and use this function

```
 <?php
function make_slug($string){
return preg_replace('/\s+/u','-',trim($string));
}
```

and use it in controller

```
$post->slug= make_slug($request->input('title'));
```

Answer (score -1):

the str_ and array_ helpers are removed from version 6 of laravel.
they are moved to a package

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

you can install this package to make it work, here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers) to refer.